# Tweaking Play! framework's asset compiler

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.2

I have my play framework's asset directory set up like so:

```
assets
└ stylesheets
  └blah.less
  └blah2.css
└templates
 └main.html
 └someOtherTemplate.html
```

I'd like to be able to have play's asset compiler move my vanilla css files into `public/` the same way it compiles and moves my less files. In the same way I'd also like to have it compile ("move") my static templates.

The reason I want to store the templates here is because I've got a single page web application and I don't want to define new routes for every template when they won't be populated with dynamic content until the ajax calls are made.

The resource generators in SBT look like they might do the trick, but the documentation isn't that great (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html)